# I need to extend the 10 item limit in @connection responses

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, aws-appsync

In AWS Amplify+ Appsync, using @connection to generate connection between tables is very easy. A simple example of this is the following `Task` table and related `Comments`

```
type Task @model{
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String
    name: String
    comments: [Comments] @connection(name:"TaskComments", sortField: "createdAt")
    status: String
}

type Comments @model{
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String
    task: Task @connection(name:"TaskComments", sortField: "createdAt")
    taskId: String
}
```

and it even autogenerates the schema for you:

```
type Task {
  id: ID!
  createdAt: String
  name: String
  comments(limit: Int, nextToken: String): ModelCommentsConnection
  Status: String
}


type Query {
    ///... other not-related queries omitted
  getTask(id: ID!): Task

}
```

The problem is that the query only returns 10 items `(Comments)` even when I have a lot more. (I can see the `nextToken` in the response but that's a different story). I want to be able to return 20, 30 or more comments per initial load.

I tried to pass `limit:1000`, but the query is ignoring it.

```
graphql(
    gql(getTask),
    {
      options: ({match: {params: {id}}}) => ({
        variables: {id, limit:1000},
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      }),
      props: ({data: {getTask: task, loading}}) => ({
        task,
        loading,
      }),
    },
   ),
```

This is a very similar question to : [AWS Amplify Graphql query on @connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716924/aws-amplify-graphql-query-on-connection)

But in my case I'm using React + AWS Amplify.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that Amplify generates for you is meant as a jumping off point. It may require some limited editing.

If you got to src/graphql/queries.js, do you see something that looks like this?

```
query GetTasks(id:ID!, limit:Int) {
    getTask(input: {id: $id}) {
      id
      createdAt
      name
      comments(limit: $limit) {
        items {
          id
        }
      }
      status
    }
}
```

If you don't see limit in this query definition, you may need to add it. (PS - I am not 100% sure on the syntax I've used above, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.)

Comment: Thanks @dustinnoyes, I know I can do this directly on the query. But this changes will be wiped out completely the moment I run `amplify push` and the auto code generator rewrite the queries.  After doing more research I concluded that is not possible for now. So I'm running 2 separated queries one for Tasks and other for Comments.  I really hope I'm wrong or maybe I just need to be patient until this is implemented.    Thanks!

Comment: This is the right answer. Thanks dustinnoyes. I realized that the auto generated Queries are only a starting point. If I need more complex behavior I need to write it manually (Add filters, limits, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just tested the following code and it seems to work well:
**i.e. possible to add ${nextToken} in order to be able to iterate over 1000 limit.**

```
 query GetTasks(id:ID!, limit:Int) {
     getTask(input: {id: $id}) {
       id
       createdAt
       name
       comments (limit: $limit nextToken: ${nextToken}) {
         items {
           id
         }
       }
       status
     } }
```

Comment: This is pretty much an exact duplicate of the accepted answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, try to comment a little bit. In this case, there is another answer with almost the same code, so expose the Pros of your answer.

Comment: I am new in here, apologies :)